# Find attribute with Xquery in OSB project (using eclipse)

Tags: xml, eclipse, xquery, osb

This is an OSB project in Eclipse.

Somewhere along a long chain of OSB processes, I have the following piece of XML, stored in $xdata:

```
<RECORDS xmlns="url1" xmlns:xsi="url2" xmlns:schemaLocation="url3" ver="v7">
...
</RECORDS>
```

I want to find the value of the attribute `ver`.
I created the following xquery in an OSB Assign node to get the attribute:

```
$xdata/occ:RECORDS/@ver
```

(I created a namespace, url3, called occ in the Namespaces part of the Assign dialog.)
The purpose of the Assign is of course to capture the "ver" attribute.

Yet, it gets nothing, and it turns out not even the `$xdata/occ:RECORDS` works, it does not give the RECORDS node of the XML, it gives nothing.
The only correct part is the $xdata, it gives the XML content, I checked the server log.

I suspect my problem is with namespaces as that's what I'm not too confident about.

Comment: Please also show how you registered that `occ` namespace.

Comment: Why `ROWS` if you want `RECORDS`? I mean, why not `occ:RECORDS`?

Comment: Thanks, har07, I corrected it, it was just my mistake when posting the question. So it's RECORDS

Comment: Jens, I just wrote occ in the Prefix field and url4 in the URI.

Comment: I named url3 as occ as I was told that's supposed to be the correct one, still it's not okay.

Comment: url3 points to an xsd, that is why I'm supposed to use that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty unexpected.
When referring to an element in a variable other than $body, you apparantly have to omit the top parent node containing the element you need. In this case, you have to omit RECORDS. So the way to get the attribute is:
$xdata/@ver